# graphicsmagick/ghostscript PDF to PNG conversion: Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript, graphicsmagick

I've been successfully able to convert many PDFs to PNGs using "gm convert", but I've been running into an issue lately with a PDF that gives me this error:

```
   **** Unknown operator: '0.0000-11728996', processed as number, value: 0.0
   **** Unknown operator: '0.0000-11728996', processed as number, value: 0.0

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.
```

I've looked around the interwebz and found that it is likely something to do with ghostscript. Could someone tell me if my PDF has errors or if it's a bug in ghostscript?

Here's the PDF: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BycjEbtUqUfNT2M0bHkteHl0NDA/edit?pli=1

Appreciate the help in advance!

Edward

Answer (score 2):

For each page, Ghostscript 9.14 says:

```
   **** Warning: replacing malformed number '0.0000-11728996' with 0.
   **** Warning: replacing malformed number '0.0000-11728996' with 0.
```

The warning says it all. The number is not formatted correctly.

Comment: FWIW the first object with a problem is object 341, which is a shading dictionary, the Coords are an array of 4 numbers, and the entries are not valid numbers. (you can verify this by opening the file with a good text editor and searching for 0.0000-11). So yes, your PDF file has errors. I guess the fact that the application that made it doesn't want to own up is not a great sign :-) We've seen this sort of malformed PDF file before but I can't remember the application that produces them.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. The PDF was from an "Export to PDF" inside a Google Drive Presentation. I guess the Google folks still have some kinks to iron out. :)